# List of supported .live() events in jQuery 1.3

Tags: live, jquery

After reading [jQuery .live()](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/08/jquerylive-event-binding-to-ajax-loaded.html) post and looking through the jQuery API I could not find a full list of events that jQuery 1.3 supports cross-browser.

Comment: Why not just switch to 1.4, which (theoretically) supports all events from `live()`?

Answer (score 2):

They are click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.

You can find them in http://api.jquery.com/live/
(section caveats)

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live):

> In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events (in addition to custom events) could be bound with .live(): click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.